# Can't access element in Pug data array

Tags: javascript, http, express, get, pug

This is my JS code from my router, I'm running a Node Express server with Pug.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var https = require('https');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var url = 'https://data.police.uk/api/forces';
    var data = [];

    https.get(url, function(res){
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function(){
            var response = JSON.parse(body)
            for (var i = 0; i< response.length; i++)
                for (var id in response[i]) {
                    data[i] = response[i]
                }
            console.log(data[0].id);
        });

    }).on('error', function(e){
        console.log("Error: ", e);
    })

    res.render('map', {
        title: 'data[0].id'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is my Pug file to be rendered

```
p Welcome to #{title}
```

The console.log in 'res.on()' works perfectly fine and shows the JSON package I was expecting. When I call this array in res.render() i.e. title: 'data[0].name' it throws an undefined error.

Comment: You're calling `render` before `data` is ever populated.

Comment: You're aware that all of this is asynchronous? `data` will be empty at the time you call `res.render`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Move your `res.render` into the area where `data` is actually populated:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var https = require('https');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var url = 'https://data.police.uk/api/forces';
    var data = [];

    https.get(url, function(res){
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function(){
            var response = JSON.parse(body)
            for (var i = 0; i< response.length; i++)
                for (var id in response[i]) {
                    data[i] = response[i]
                }
            console.log(data[0].id);
            res.render('map', {
                title: 'data[0].id'
            });
        });

    }).on('error', function(e){
        console.log("Error: ", e);
    })

});

module.exports = router;
```

It's not populated everywhere, that's not how asynchronous code or scoping works.

Comment: Tried this, the connection is now being refused. The response from the server is now empty. The error message I'm getting is res.render is not a function.

Comment: @MichaelDepaye, that sounds like a separate issue. What is the URL?

Comment: localhost:3000, all the code is in the index.js route.